# MongoDB Ruby aggregation with dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I'm having trouble with the MongoDB ruby driver (via mongoid) using aggregation.

I would like to match against a date using comparison operators.

```
match = { '$match' => { 'created_at' => { '$gte' => DateTime.parse('2012-08-01') } } }
group = { '$group' => { '_id' => 'foo' } }
MyModel.collection.aggregate([match, group])
```

I don't know what to put in the first line for the date. The code as written above will throw me an `undefined method __bson_dump__ for DateTime` exception. Using a string doesn't seem to work, either.

Any suggestions are welcome. MongoID's built in methods give me what I need for the selection but not for the grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, use a `Time` object instead of `DateTime`

```
match = { '$match' => { 'created_at' => { '$gte' => Time.parse('2012-08-01') } } }
```

Comment: It is not working, It convert the date to String, which can not be compared to DateTime fields in Mongo

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
h = { '$match' => { 'created_at' => { '$gte' => new Date("2012/08/01") } } }
```

Comment: So the code example I gave is ruby, this looks like how we would do it in javascript.